# Android——How can i know whether the app is autostart or not

Tags: android, permissions, autostart

I want to know whether the user allows autostart permissions of the app. I have already tried this:

```
ComponentName mComponentName = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),".AutoStartReceiver");
int a = getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(mComponentName);
```

the autostart permission can be granted and denied by security app，but I don't know how to get the status in my application.
[such as the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKNPi.png)

Comment: I had tried to use "ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...)" and get get a list of receivers,but the state had not changed  when the user denied the permissions

Answer (score 1):

you are probably using this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

After that, you can implement a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pi);
}}
```

And just add the class to your manifest-file:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

---

To check directly, if you have Autostart permissions, use this:

```
int p = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity.this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED);
if (p == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Yay, you have the receive boot completed (= Autostart) permission!
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If the Alarm is "called" you know, that the user allows the permission. If you need the information immediatly, just check it via this: int p = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity.this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED);
And use if to check it: if (p == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {/*...*/}

Comment: The question is about how to get if the specific app has a `BOOT_COMPLETE` receiver registered.

Comment: Ah alright, misunderstood your question then.. Sorry mate :(

Comment: That's not my question, actually it is how I understood it. I realized that your answer may be correct, since I might missunderstood question too. Removed downvote, sorry

Comment: Thank you for answering ,I'm sorry that I express is not clear

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of receivers, registered for a specific intent, you can use 
Use [`PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.htm) and [`queryBroadcastReceivers()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

To get a list for `BOOT_COMPLETE`, construct an intent with `BOOT_COMPLETE` action

Comment: Thank you for answering ,I'm sorry that I express is not clear